# jsf standard converter along with primefaces select one menu

Tags: primefaces, converters

When the "select" option of the select one menu is selected, the default value is saved in DB as 0. Can I change this to null?
The value of select one menu is bound to a bean property. To achieve this, I have used the converter attribute of the select one menu component. But it does not seem to convert empty string to null. What am I missing?

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2" >
    <p:outputLabel value="District" />
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{cJData.cJ.dC}" converter="javax.faces.Long">
        <p:ajax listener="#{cJActionHandler.selectDC}"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{cJData.DCs}" var="coun" 
            itemLabel="#{coun.name}" itemValue="#{coun.id}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="#{null}" />
```

As the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/) of `LongConverter#getAsObject` say - this is the method which is called when you submit th value - the `Long` converter will convert only `null` to `null`.